# Failing to scrape the full page from Google Search results using selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Google results using selenium chromedriver. Before, I used requests + Beautifulsoup to scrape google Results, and this worked, however I got blocked from Google after around 300 results. I've been reading into this topic and it seems to me that using selenium + webdriver is less easily blocked by Google.

Now, I'm trying to scrape Google results using selenium. I would like to scrape the title, link and description of all items. Essentially, I want to do this: [How to scrape all results from Google search results pages (Python/Selenium ChromeDriver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487987/how-to-scrape-all-results-from-google-search-results-pages-python-selenium-chro)

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"css selector","selector":"h3"}   (Session info:
> chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Therefore, I'm trying another code. This code is able to scrape some, but not ALL the titles + descriptions. See picture below. I cannot scrape the last 4 titles, and the last 5 descriptions are also empty. Any clues on this? Much appreciated.

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

root = "https://www.google.com/"
url = "https://google.com/search?q="

query = 'Why do I only see the first 4 results?'  # Fill in google query
query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)
link = url + query

print(f'Main link to search for: {link}')

options = Options()
# options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, './/h3')))

link_tag    = './/div[@class= "yuRUbf"]/a'
title_tag   = './/h3'
description_tag = './/span[@class= "aCOpRe"]'


titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(title_tag)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(link_tag)
descriptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(description_tag)

for t in titles:
    print('title:', t.text)
for l in links:
    print('links:', l.get_attribute("href"))
for d in descriptions:
    print('descriptions:', d.text)    

# Why are the last 4 titles and the last 5 descriptions empty??
```

Image of the results: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause those 4 are not the actual links, Google always show **"People also ask"**. If you see their DOM structure

```
<div style="padding-right:24px" jsname="xXq91c" class="cbphWd" data-
kt="KjCl66uM1I_i7PsBqYb-irfI74DmAeDWm-uv7IveYLKIxo-bn9L1H56X2ZSUy9L-6wE" 
data-hveid="CAgQAw" data-ved="2ahUKEwjAoJ2ivd3wAhXU-nMBHWj1D8EQuk4oAHoECAgQAw">
How do I get Google to show all results?
</div>
```

it is not an anchor tag so you won't see **href tag** so your links list will have 4 empty value cause there are 4 divs like that.

to grab those 4 you need to use different locator :

XPATH : `//*[local-name()='svg']/../following-sibling::div[@style]`

```
title_tags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[local-name()='svg']/../following-sibling::div[@style]")
for title in title_tags:
   print(title.text)
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, however I'm also not seeing the links referring to the "books.google.nl" titles/descriptions. Any clues on that?

Comment: @CrossLord : Is that a new issue ? if yes can you close this one if your specific issue related to this ticket has been resolved ? if that's a new issue feel free to raise a new ticket.

Comment: thanks for your input first of all. No it's the same issue actually. I totally get what you are saying, and your code is definitely helpful to scrape those results, but there are also a couple more google search results AFTER the "People also ask" section. I'm trying to get those too, but they're not showing.

Comment: @CrossLord : Your existing code works fine for the search results `AFTER the "People also ask" section.`